# How to use session id in model using Anorm query with Scala Play Framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I need a query which checks if two users ( current user and some other user) have common authors in their libraries, but I don't know how to write the id of the current user inside a model. 
Is it allowed to use the id of the user in the current session inside of a model?

```
def getAuthors(friend_id: Long): Int   = {
    DB.withConnection{ implicit connection =>
        val nrAuthors = SQL("select count(*) from book where author in (select author from book where user_id = userIdFromCurrentSession) and user_id = " + friend_id).as(scalar[Int].single) 
        nrAuthors
     }
}
```

Comment: Current user in what session? This isn't very informative. It sounds less of a question about Anorm and more of a question about the authentication system you're using and haven't told us anything about.

Comment: I have a list of users, each of them has his own library and  the current user, the logged one. I need to write a query verifying if the current user has common authors with one of the users from that list.

Comment: In my controller, I'm saving the session with the following method


trait Secured {

      def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("username")

}

Thank you!

Comment: I know how to solve my problem...I will add to my function getAuthors 2 parameters, def getAuthoros(friend_id: Long, currendUser_id: Long)
and in my controller I can do something like
var nrAuthors = Book.getAuthors(id, user.id.get)

Comment: Better to pass the value as parameter: `SQL"select count(*) from book where author in (select author from book where user_id = userIdFromCurrentSession) and user_id = $friend_id".as(scalar[Int].single)`